# Article "la" before women names

Tags: regional, articles, name, proper-nouns

I spent some time in a few of the northern provinces of Italy. When I was in Tuscany I noticed that when mentioning a woman by name they would use the feminine article "la" with the name, e.g. "la Sara" instead of "Sara". Is this just a quirk of the Toscanacci, or does it happen elsewhere? And in formal Italian is this incorrect?

Comment: I am sorry to close your question: it was a good one! But it is an almost exact duplicate of another. Please keep asking them :)

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect in formal Italian but used in informal Italian in northern Italy. In some places like Lombardy article "Il" is used before masculine names too, like "Il Mario" or "Il Giuseppe"

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!